# Android Studio does not open, with no error indicated

Tags: android-studio-2.2

I downloaded Android Studio from the official website. Per the instructions, I located JDK home and Java in system variables and environment variables.

Now, when I am trying to launch the software, it's not opening. No black screen, no "loaded" screen, nothing. No signs of any error. Please help me in opening it.

System configs = 8GB RAM 2.2GHz processor, 4 GB graphics, 1 TB hardisk

Comment: check the proper jdk in enviromental variable and set the path in enviromental variable path.

Comment: are u sure that u opening studio64?

Comment: yes i am opening studio 64 i have already set the path in environment variable still no signs of whey